# Shadow during activity transition. (as seen in material design guidelines)

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I'm trying to implement the animation seen in material design guidelines:

[image]

I've implemented the animation, but I can't get the shadow to the left of the uppermost activity to appear. How do you activate that?